# how to improve webpage speed in drupal

Tags: drupal, mod-pagespeed

I have a big content website which is hosted on rackspace in USA. The site downloads time is close to 12 seconds despite using CDN module, image jss etc. as per Pagespeed, website gets close to 85/100 and on Yslow it gets B grade. How can I bring website speed to less than 3 seconds. I have already installed APC

Comment: You have to analyze what are the issues that are hogging your website. Maybe some slow queries, or is your website most used by authenticated users, based on that you can proceed further. Use Apache benchmark to analyze your website speeds. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Answer (score 0):

Memcached and Varnish will drastically improve your page load speeds. [This presentation](http://2bits.com/drupal-performance/presentation-34-million-page-views-day-92-million-month-one-server-and-drupal.html) from 2bits introduced me to the world of server optimization. Also check out the lullabot series on improving performance.

Comment: i have see this ppt by 2 bits but thts very funny. He starts with drupal but removes all drupal modules like CCK etc so at the end u wonder if they are improving drupal only or somethimg else?

Comment: Did you try memcached, varnish? Are there any slow sql queries that hogging your memory.